# using absolute import paths in Python code with VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-packaging, vscode-python

The workspace folder is `myapp` and the folder structure is the following:

```
myapp/
    main.py
    __init__.py 
    module/
        __init__.py
        math.py
```

In the top level workspace folder in `main.py` I would like to import the math package using an absolute path like so:

```
from myapp.module import math
```

This throws an error "No module named 'myapp'" and the pylance addon also fails to find the package. Everything works if i remove the myapp prefix:

```
from module import math
```

How do i resolve this in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

You can get [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) through:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

The parent folder path of executed python script will be added to PYTHONPATH automatically([refer](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path)).

> **As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,**
> **path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to**
> **invoke the Python interpreter.** If the script directory is not
> available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
> script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string,
> which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.
> **Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries**
> **inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.**

The `parent folder path` of `myapp folder` does not exist in the `PYTHONPATH`, so `myapp` will not be treated as a module, so `from myapp.module import math` will not work.

While folder path of `myapp` in the PYTHONPATH, so `module` can be searched, then `from module import math` will work.